# "You can only post once every 40 minutes" on different sites

Tags: discussion, question-restrictions

This morning I posted a question on a SE site. Then realized a different SE site would be more appropriate.

I proceeded to delete the question on the first site and copied it to the second, but I got the dreaded "*You can only post once every 40 minutes.*", even if the question was deleted from a *different* SE site.

I have only the affiliation reputation on both of those sites. Now I'm sitting here waiting for the 40 minutes to pass.

Paradoxically, as a trusted user in SO, I'm more likely to come to other SE sites to ask a few things about topics that are new to me (as opossed to answering in SO), yet I feel more limited.

Maybe trusted users from other sites should have slightly lower restrictions than <125 on the fellow communities? In particular in order to ask a couple of questions.

Comment: @NoahCristino yes, I read it, but that question is for low-rep users. But I think this should not apply to trusted users (say above 1000 rep) on other sites.

Comment: @jjmontes Well `125 rep` isn't that much and you are considered a `new user` when you have `< 125`

Comment: I am aware of the mechanism. My question is more about whether this could be changed. I think the current rule is a side effect of the implementation (which just looks at your rep in the current site). But as I see it, there is no functional reason not to allow 2 or 3 questions for high-rep users from other sites.

Comment: @jjmontes Oh. Like it totals up all your rep?

Comment: That could be a solution. But only for this or similar limits, and I'd still keep a limit (ie 3 questions in 40 minutes). Other limitations would of course be site-only.

Comment: @gnat Thanks for the finding! I have upvoted that question, it exactly expresses my thoughts.

Comment: Yesterday I had folks calling for me to be fired because I wasn't hobbling cross-site privileges even more. Today it's more cross-site privileges. Tomorrow, probably less again. I feel like this is probably a good equilibrium. 40 minutes is a good healthy walk, BTW!

Comment: @Shog9 but... you know, and SO knows, I'm not a spammer. It's not about equilibrium or policy.

Comment: It is though, because whatever policy is in place applies to everyone - and folks wear different hats in different topics. I think the right solution here is an explicit "move my question to [this other site]" option, exposed for new questions - that'd benefit everyone.

Comment: I'm afraid I still don't agree. I may be a noob in other topic but I'm definitely not a spammer, and a high rep users usually know how to pose a decent question even in topics off their usual expertise area. I still may want to write two questions across sites with <125 rep, and there doesn't seem to be a real reason for a fellow high rep user not to do so.

Comment: That "move my question" solution only solves his exact problem. More generally, as exemplified by me, I have two [separate] questions for different sites (the first is a meta "question" too!) right now, and I found this after being stopped trying to submit the second (even though I'm a trusted user, albeit on another site, also)

Comment: The same happened to me. I found a simple and straightforward solution: waiting 40 minutes.

Comment: This question is word for word my situation. Posted on Server Faults and should have posted on hardwarerecs. I am a new user on both but over 11k rep on SO. Yet I get the same must wait 40 min to post on hardwarerecs. Somewhat inconvenient. It would be nice of you had an overall profile check that said Oh this users already has enough rep to understand how to post properly. Something along those lines.

Comment: You generally get it wrong when u r new to a site, i.e. rep 100. I think if one has made 1 post, then deleted it, one should not have to wait 40 mins to make another post. It should see that your actual posted posts is at zero for the current interval. Why am I commenting, I am waiting for 40 mins...

Comment: @run_the_race you are right about that. but we can only wait for 40 minutes :(

Comment: I have the same issue. While posting a question on a SE site I noticed one tag was duplicated. When I tried to raise the issue on the SE meta site I got the "40 minutes" error. I now have to wait for 40 minutes for no valid reason.

Comment: I have the same issue too. Although I have a 11k network reputation with 11 gold, 75 silver and 200 bronze badges. When I enter a site especially one that is recently released and want to add some helpful questions, this does limit content generation a lot. I think a high Network Reputation should lower this to 10 minutes instead of 40 minutes.

Answer (score 6):

Instead of deleting you could have just flagged it `in need of moderator intervention` so the mods could move it.
[image: moved]

Comment: I was moving from Amateur Radio to Signal Processing. I thought doing that would kind of be moderator abuse... I could easily have done the move myself.

Comment: Some SEs do not like doing this.  Maybe the policy has changed since this answer was written, but more often than not, I'm told to delete and post elsewhere.

Comment: @DanWhaley I've never had to do this but I could see where mods would get mad.

Comment: it's also not obvious this is the thing to do. I had to be bitten by this, find this answer, and then know what to do