# Getting "You can only post once every 40 minutes." on my first post of the day (to any SE site)

Tags: bug, asking-questions, rate-limiting

On my very first post to any SE site today, I was blocked by the "You can only post once every 40 minutes" message. **I haven't posted to any SE site in at least 24 hours**.

I have read ["You can only post once every 40 minutes" on different sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/292197/230092) and other linked duplicates, but they explain that posting on any SE site starts the timer.

Comment: Is your IP address shared with other people, for example in a university?

Comment: Yes, the IP address might be shared with others in the company. However, I was logged in. I would have thought that you would be able to distinguish between different users with the same IP, as long as they are logged in.

Comment: @mhwombat no, it's impossible to tell if two accounts from same IP belong to two different persons, or if they were created by the same person in order to dodge question ban. The few who abuse this cause all others to suffer.