# How can one avoid the 40 min compulsory break in between two questions?

Tags: feature-request, questions, asking-questions, rate-limiting

If someone has an account on Stack Overflow and also on Mathematics Stack Exchange and Physics Stack Exchange and if that person asks a question on Stack Overflow at 11am, they will have to wait until 11:40 am before posting a new question even while being able to posting on other Stack Exchange sites

Please guide me about this compulsory 40 min break? And how one can avoid it? Or there is no legal way of avoiding it all?

Comment: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/292197/you-can-only-post-once-every-40-minutes-on-different-sites

Comment: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/281953/does-the-new-user-rate-limit-apply-even-when-you-are-a-new-user-on-only-one-site

Comment: I'm confused as to how you know about this limit, considering you only signed up today, only on Stack Overflow, and (as far as I can tell) haven't posted any questions.

Comment: @F1Krazy I also thought so. It looks a bit suspicious yes.

Comment: If you are the kind of person who can't wait 40 minutes to ask another question, you are *exactly* the person who should wait 40 minutes to ask another question.

Answer (score 17):

Spend that 40 minutes researching the next question you want to ask. Perhaps you'll find the solution yourself. If not you should at least have a good question that you can demonstrate you've researched thoroughly. I.e. don't treat it as a break where you put your feet up and just wait for the time to pass.

If you want to bang out questions every few minutes you've not done any research or looked to see whether we've already answered that problem. You've likely not broken the problem down into something we could answer either. If you can say I have this problem and I'm stuck at this specific point and I've tried this and this and this to solve it, that's much better than just throwing out a "how do I solve X" question and hoping someone will give you the whole answer. Maybe most of that answer is stuff you already knew but didn't tell us.

Answer (score 14):

The very simple answer is "You don't".

Fundamentally - those rate limits are there to, well rate limit. While the diversity of sites is very nice - sometimes there's "negative externalities". People posting on multiple sites - sometimes off topic and so on

I guess the counter to that is "what questions of lasting significance can't wait 40 minutes?"

You can spend the time polishing up and working on the problem, maybe even finding a solution on your own to share with the world. You could even go for a walk (or walk your dog) and give your question one final look over and polish it before you hit the post button.

So fundamentally the trick is not to *avoid* the rate limit. It is to turn it to your advantage.